# Search Instance Stuck at "Starting" in WFE

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

My Search Instance Stuck in "Starting" in my WFE.But its "Started" in my App Server.

I Just followed this article [SharePoint 2013 Search Configuration PowerShell Script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_-_inside_the_lines/2013/08/07/sharepoint-2013-search-configuration-powershell-script/) to configure my search topology...

Comment: anything in event log or uls log? what is your search topology?

Comment: I just followed the above URL(1WFE and 1 Apps Server) to configure search topology in my 3 tier farm and i did't find any error meesage in the Event log

Comment: Without log details, we cannot help. Do you find any error in uls?

Comment: How long has it been stuck at starting?

Answer (score 1):

Check permission on

1. SharePoint Search service in services.mcs
2. Search Service Application
3. Search application pool
4. Search databases

In 9 out of 10 cases, there is something wrong with permission.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Benny's answer, check the SharePoint Timer Service and SharePoint Admin Services are running on the WFE. Possibly even restart them.

Comment: Now,i able to stop the search instance in my WFE.However i would like know few things 1.Do the SharePoint Timer service should run on same service accounts which is running in the Apps server?

Comment: The SharePoint Timer Service should be running as the farm account on all servers.

Comment: FYI the farm account is used to run timer jobs, of which should be a separate account to the application pools.